# Copy and Move Idiom in children classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class A
{
    std::string val1;
    A(std::string str) : val1(std::move(str)){}
};

class B: A
{
    B(std::string str) : A(str){}
};
```

In this case, `str` would be copied twice, or not?
What is the best way to use Copy & Move idiom with children's classes?

Comment: `A(str)`->`A(std::move(str))` Now it will be moved twice ( + construction at the call site).

Comment: But since `std::move` is basically just a cast, I expect that also after your suggestion it will have to be copied twice, since in both constructor there is no & neither &&. Am I wrong?

Comment: You don't need `&` or `&&` to have a move. It is a constructor of `std::string` which decides whether to move or to copy. A constructor is selected by an overload resolution. It is affected by the value category of `str`, which in turn is affected by `std::move()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to C++, it is maybe a good idea to simply investigate what is happening if you execute your code instead of take maybe wrong assumptions.

To see what is happening, simply replace `std::string` with your own class and put some debug output in it.

```
struct mystring
{
    mystring() { std::cout << "Default" << std::endl; }

    mystring( mystring&& ) { std::cout << "Move" << std::endl; }
    mystring( const mystring& ) { std::cout << "Copy" << std::endl; }

    mystring& operator=( const mystring& ) { std::cout << "Copy assign" << std::endl; return *this; }
    mystring& operator=( mystring&& ) { std::cout << "Move assign" << std::endl; return *this; }

    ~mystring() { std::cout << "Delete" << std::endl; }
};
```

And with some test code

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
    mystring ms;
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
    B b(std::move(ms));
    std::cout << "3" << std::endl;
}
```

You will see:

```
1
Default
2
Copy
Copy
Move
Delete
Delete
3
Delete
Delete
```

Your question "In this case, str would be copied twice, or not?" is answered: Yes, it copies twice!

you have always to follow [rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) if you also want forwarding/move to work as expected.

This will result into:

```
class A
{
    private:
        mystring val1;

    public:
        A(): val1{}{}
        A( const mystring& str ): val1( str ) {} 
        A(mystring&& str) : val1(std::move(str)){}

        // if you also want to assign a string later
        A& operator=(const mystring& str ) { std::cout << "copy string to A" << std::endl; val1 = str; return *this; }
        A& operator=(mystring&& str ) { std::cout << "move string to A" << std::endl; val1 = (std::move(str)); return *this; }

        // and now all the stuff for copy/move of class itself:
        A( const A& a): val1{ a.val1} {}
        A( A&& a): val1{ std::move(a.val1)} {}
        A& operator=( const A& a) { std::cout << "copy from A" << std::endl; val1=a.val1; return *this; }
        A& operator=( A&& a) { std::cout << "move from A" << std::endl; val1=std::move(a.val1); return *this; }
};


class B: public A
{

    public:
        B(): A{}{}
        B( const mystring& str ): A( str ) {} 
        B(mystring&& str) : A(std::move(str)){}

        // and now all the stuff for copy/move of class itself:
        B( const B& b): A{ b} {}
        B( B&& b): A{ std::move(b)} {}
        B& operator=( const B& b) { std::cout << "copy from B" << std::endl; A::operator=(b); return *this; }
        B& operator=( B&& b) { std::cout << "move from B" << std::endl; A::operator=(std::move(b)); return *this; }
};
```

And now test also this:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
    mystring ms;
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
    B b(std::move(ms));
    std::cout << "3" << std::endl;

    //   
    std::cout << "4" << std::endl;
    B b2;

    // and now move assign
    std::cout << "5" << std::endl;
    b = std::move(b2);
    std::cout << "6" << std::endl;
}
```

Result:

```
1
Default
2
Move
3
4
Default
5
move from B
move from A
Move assign
6
Delete
Delete
Delete
```

Now you have a single move for first step and the move assign works also as expected.

See it running [here](https://godbolt.org/z/9MMffdGnK)

Answer (score 2):

In cases like this, the best way to be sure is often to log copies and moves. Simply wrap `std::string` into a custom class or struct with custom copy and move semantics, like this:

```cpp
class StringWrapper
{
public:
    std::string data;

    StringWrapper(const char* cstr)
        : data(cstr) {}

    // Copy constructor and assignment
    StringWrapper(const StringWrapper& other)
        : data(other.data)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor!\n";
    }

    StringWrapper& operator=(const StringWrapper& other)
    {
        data = other.data;
        std::cout << "Copy assignment!\n";
        return *this;
    }

    // Move constructor and assignment
    StringWrapper(StringWrapper&& other)
        : data(std::move(other.data))
    {
        std::cout << "Move constructor!\n";
    }

    StringWrapper& operator=(StringWrapper&& other)
    {
        data = std::move(other.data);
        std::cout << "Move assignment!\n";
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Then to replace every use of `std::string` by `StringWrapper`:

```cpp
class A
{
public: // Public for testing
    StringWrapper val1;
    A(StringWrapper str) : val1(std::move(str)){}
};

class B: public A // Private inheritance should be avoided
{
public: // Public for testing
    B(StringWrapper str) : A(std::move(str)){}
};
```

With a small test:

```cpp
int main()
{
    StringWrapper strA("hello");
    A a(strA);
    std::cout << a.val1.data << '\n';

    StringWrapper strB("world");
    B b(strB);
    std::cout << b.val1.data << '\n';
}
```

Then to analyze the output:

```
Copy constructor!
Move constructor!
hello
Copy constructor!
Copy constructor!
Move constructor!
world
```

The first copy happens when passing `strA` by value. It is necessary since we don't want changes to `strA` to affect `a.val1`.

The second copy is very similar: it occurs when passing `strB` by value. It is also necessary for the same reason.

The third copy, on the other hand, is redundant. It occurs when passing `str` to the parent constructor in `B`'s constructor. `str` will be destroyed at the end of the construction, so we better move its content than copy it:

```cpp
class B: public A
{
public:
    B(StringWrapper str) : A(std::move(str)){} // Replaced copy with move
};
```

Fixed!

```
Copy constructor!
Move constructor!
hello
Copy constructor!
Move constructor!
Move constructor!
world
```